# Extending properly in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a template where I need to load certain information and would like to do that only once so I have to create an extended controller called MY_Controller.
However I'm stuck with extending the $data array which is inside MY_Controller to other controllers.

Here's MY_Controller.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        public $layout;
        public $id;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->output->nocache();

            $this->load->model('subject_model');
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $this->load->model('survey_model');

            // This is the info I need for every controller and method in my app
            $data['total_subjects'] = $this->subject_model->countSubjects();
            $data['check_if_already_posted_it_survey'] = $this->survey_model->checkIfAlreadyPostedSurvey('it_survey', $this->id);
            $data['total_users'] = $this->user_model->countUsers();
            $data['subjects'] = $this->subject_model->get_all_subjects();
            $data['schools'] = $this->subject_model->get_all_schools();
            $data['subject_name'] = $this->subject_model->getSubjectNameById($this->id);
            $data['school_name'] = $this->subject_model->getSchoolNameById($this->id);

            $this->id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $this->layout = 'layout/dashboard';
        }
    }
?>
```

This of course gives me an error. What should I do to get this one to work properly without repeating myself and loading that same data array in every method because so far that is the only way I've got it to work without errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you to access `$data` array from other controller you have to set this as a property

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $layout;
    public $id;
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->output->nocache();

        $this->load->model('subject_model');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('survey_model');

        // This is the info I need for every controller and method in my app
        $data['total_subjects'] = $this->subject_model->countSubjects();
        $data['check_if_already_posted_it_survey'] = $this->survey_model->checkIfAlreadyPostedSurvey('it_survey', $this->id);
        $data['total_users'] = $this->user_model->countUsers();
        $data['subjects'] = $this->subject_model->get_all_subjects();
        $data['schools'] = $this->subject_model->get_all_schools();
        $data['subject_name'] = $this->subject_model->getSubjectNameById($this->id);
        $data['school_name'] = $this->subject_model->getSchoolNameById($this->id);

        $this->data = $data;

        $this->id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->layout = 'layout/dashboard';
    }
}
```

Also one suggestion if you are in a all php code **`remove your php end tag`**